# How can I use `wmic` in a Windows PE script?

Tags: windows, wmic, winpe

I'm trying to determine the computer model (e.g., "Optiplex 9010") in a batch script running in the context of Windows PE 3.1.  When running Windows proper, I can do this using `wmic csproduct` or `wmic bios` but neither of these return any data when running Windows PE.  (This also seems to be true of most or all other classes.)

I've already installed the `winpe-wmi.cab` package to support WMI.  Using `wmic path` instead of an alias makes no difference.

How can I make my `wmic` commands work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that most `wmic` commands, including both `wmic csproduct` and `wmic bios`, will work if you install the `winpe-scripting.cab` package in addition to the `winpe-wmi.cab` package.